# take in a sequence as well as the value you need to find and returns a sequence of exactly three resistors that sums up to the required value R

Tags: python, dictionary, sequence

I cannot pass the private cases my school provided. They say "Does your code work with other kind of sequence?"Can anybody help me to figure it out?
Write the function triplets(seq, R) which takes in a sequence of resistor seq as well as the value you need to find and returns a sequence of exactly three resistors that sums up to the required value R if there is such a solution.  Otherwise returns None.  You can assume that the input sequence contains only integers (int) sorted in ascending order.

```
def triplets(seq, R):
    i=0
    check=0
    list1=[]
    while len(seq)>=3:
      i=seq[0]
      seq.pop(0)
      check=R-i
      for m, j in enumerate(seq):
        k = m+1
        if seq[k:].count(check - j) > 0:
            for n in range(seq[k:].count(check - j)):
                b = seq.index(check - j, k)
                list1.append((i,seq[m],seq[b]))
                k = b+1

    if len(list1)==0:
        return None
    else:
        return min(list1)
```

[image: my codes]

Comment: can you add your code in question

Comment: still cannot pass the private cases

Comment: you can remove the picture code is enough as these both are same

Comment: can yuo provide sample input and output

Comment: so you want a function which provide the triplet whose sume is equal to R ?

Comment: yes sample: print(triplets([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 10))
print(triplets([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 25))
print(triplets([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 100))

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-triplet-that-sum-to-a-given-value/ this will help you